# Vector iterators < or !=

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Could anyone help me understand whether there's a big difference in `!=` and `<` when it comes to talk about vector iterators within a `for` loop?

I mean, no matter whether you use `!=` and `<`, the result should be the same?

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
    // DO STUFF
```

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i < vec.end(); i++)
    // DO STUFF
```

I am aware that the most common way is to use `!=`, but would `<` be a big issue if used?

Comment: < could be slower than != since it needs to check that the rhs is after the lhs; but that's going to be somewhat dependent on implementation.

Comment: OT: Consider using a range based for loop.

Comment: [This iterator categories reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Iterator_categories) could be helpful to read through.

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673762/why-is-used-with-iterators

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`operator<` is only supported for [random access iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). `std::vector::iterator` is a random access iterator, so both `i != vec.end()` and `i < vec.end()` are supported and valid and make no difference in your example.

If you had a container that does not support random access iterators (e.g. `std::list`), `i < list.end()` would not compile.

The general recommendation is to use postfix increment only when it is necessary though because it may create an unnecessary copy when the iterator is non-trivial, so `++i` is cleaner and may be faster.

Also, if the loop calls a function whose definition is not available in this translation unit `vec.end()` is going to be reloaded from memory on each loop iteration, which might cause an unnecessary cache miss. You can avoid that reload by saving the value into a local variable, so that the compiler is certain that the local variable is inaccessible to any other function:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator i = vec.begin(), j = vec.end(); i < j; ++i)
    // ...
```

Even better, you may like to use range-for loops that avoid these performance pitfalls for you:

```
for(auto const& elem : vec)
    // ...
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a container where vec.end would be recomputed every time? (I'm curious bc I don't want to write code that does that)

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash https://godbolt.org/g/VyQMkH - in `slow` it reloads `end()` from memory, in `fast` it keeps it in a register.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash So, the thing is that the compiler has to *prove* that the vector is not modified if you invoke `.end()` to cache it, and proving that is often hard.  If you cache it, it is up to *you* to prove that (or your code risks UB).  Proving it is sometimes hard.  Which of these two you prefer is a choice.

Comment: It's sometimes worth iterating backwards just to avoid the reload of end() ... if you're indexing into the vector, you need the value of begin(), so you can just do `auto i = v.end(); while (i != v.begin()) { /* do something with *--i */ }`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin you're right, it was ~1am here and not thinking. Could we delete these comments and never speak of it? :o)

Answer (score 11):

The entire philosophy behind the `STL` part of the Standard Library (the containers, iterators and algorithms) is to minimize the programatic distinctions between the containers. They exhibit different properties but how you program them is designed to be as similar as possible.

This makes them easier to learn and easier to use *generically*. That means you can write one *generic* function (or algorithm) and have it apply to any other container (or as many as possible).

With that in mind it is beneficial to use syntax that is common to all containers and iterators *where possible*.

Only some containers' iterators allow `<` comparisons but **all** containers' iterators accept `!=`. For that reason I would recommend always using `!=` as a matter of consistency and to facilitate your code being easily ported to a different container.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph: more generally, only some iterator types allow `<` comparisons but all iterator types (other than simple output iterators) accept `!=`. Containers are one source of iterators, but they are not the only one.

Answer (score 9):

It does make a difference, although not for `std::vector`. All iterators are equality comparable, so `!=` will always work. Only random access iterators are less than comparable, as is `std::vector`, so in your case it wouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Not all iterators are equality comparable. Output iterators, for example.

Comment: @Incomputable This statement also appears in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673775/3182664 - if it is wrong, then the answer there should be fixed (according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator it should be safe to say that "All **input** iterators are equality-comparable" - possibly with a link to this exact site)