# why not use < but != in loop for c++?

Tags: c++, loops

```
for (string::size_type ix = 0; ix != str.size(); ++ix)
```

why not use `!=` instead of `<` in loop for C++?

Comment: a bit hard to tell what you want to argue? Why not choose `<`, indeed? Most of the time in C++ you'd use iterators, which then makes sense with `!=` and the value returned by the iterator function when encountering the end of the list. In your case `<` looks sensible.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use `<`.

Comment: There is a duplicate with high view count and lots of good answers, let's see if I could find it before this question gets closed...

Comment: Conventionwise, < is preferred. `!=` is correct but it's not common, and thus looks like an error.

Comment: I was too slow... Anyway, check out this answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8884617/335858).

Comment: @mbratch - +1 just in case the container .size method was broken and returned -1, using < is a bit more robust.

Comment: I just think it states the intent better. :)

Comment: I stand corrected (see other similar questions/answers)

Comment: In many error cases, `<` will terminate while `!=` will continue to iterate.  For a loooooong time.  This is the traditional reason for preferring `<`.  Also, Fortran DO loops and the like always implemented with `<` (when using a positive increment), so it's familiar.

Comment: Voted to remain closed - @dasblinkenlight found a duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [format of for loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783822/format-of-for-loops) (thx to dasblinkenlight for finding it)

Answer (score 4):

It's a matter of preference mostly - the syntax is usually considered in human readable form to mean *"while ix is not equal to (value) do (action) and keep incrementing ix"*. This is why it's often typed as `!=` to directly 'translate' the "is not equal" consideration.

For most loops it doesn't matter which one you use, there is however the consideration that using `<` instead of `!=` reduces the chance of overflow errors occurring, for example when using:

```
for(int i = 0; i != 25; i += 2)
```

While it is obvious in this case the loop will never terminate, if the `25` or `2` come from another source it might not be. Thus it's preferable to use `<` consistently as a precautionary habit.

Answer (score 4):

`why not use != instead of < in loop for C++?`

Sometimes this will lead to some bugs hard to catch. If I want to print odd numbers below 10, then `!=` is not the right choice. Following loop runs for ever.

```
for (int i=1; i!=10; i+=2)
{
     cout << i << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `!=` idiom is necessary when you use iterators rather than integer indexes. If you often use iterators it just becomes habit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, and in C, I think `<` is more common.  In C++, the STL adds a new twist:

```
for(FooType::iterator i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); i++)
    ... do stuff ...
```

Should use `!=`, because in some (most?) cases `<` will not even be defined for the iterator type.  So you might want to use `!=` in non-STL loops too, just for consistency.

**Note:** I normally use `<`, because as  other answers say, it means you can't miss the sentry value.  But this is no big deal; if you are *unexpectedly* missing the sentry, then you already have a bug.