# why does visual studio have i++ post increment as a default for autocompleting for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

so this is what visual studio gives when auto completing a for loop.
I have been told that ++i is more effecient than i++ as the pre increment does not require the comiler to create a temporary variable to store i. and that I should use ++i unless I actually require i++. is there any reason that visual studio does this as a default or am I just overthinking it?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Does it do it for more complicated types like a `std::vector::iterator`?  For an `int` both cases are the same so it doesn't matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c/24887#24887

Comment: For `int`, I expect compiler to generate same code as value of `i++` is not used.

Comment: The answer to "why" is: "convention." and the fact that it doesn't matter typically once optimizations are done. For more see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484462/difference-between-pre-increment-and-post-increment-in-a-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this answer is based on my experience rather than on any hard facts, so please take it with a grain of salt.

## Reasons for i++ as the default loop incrementor

### Postfix vs Prefix

The postfix incrementor i++ produces a temporary pre-incremented value that's passed 'upwards' in the expression, then variable i is subsequently incremented.

The prefix incrementor ++i does not produce a temporary object, but directly increments i and passes the incremented result to the expression.

### Performance

Looking at two simple loops, one using i++, and the other ++i, let us examine the generated assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     //        
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
       //
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Generates the following assembly using GCC:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 4
        jg      .L2
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
.L5:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 4
        jg      .L4
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

.L3 corresponds to the first loop, and .L5 corresponds to the second loop. The compiler optimizes away any differences in this case resulting in identical code, so no performance difference.

### Appearance

Looking at the following three loops, which one appeals to you most aesthetically?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     //        
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
       //
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i+=1) {
       //
   }
```

For me i+=1 is right out, and ++i just feels sort of... *backwards*

### Ergonomics

- i++) - Your hand is already in the correct position to type ) after typing ++
- ++i) - Requires moving from upper row to homerow and back

### History

Older C programmers, and current C programmers who write systems level code make frequent use of i++ to allow for writing very compact code such as:

```
// print some char * s
while(*s)
    putc(*s++);

// strcpy from src to dest
while (*dest++=*src++);
```

Because of this i++ became the incrementor C programmers reach for first, eventually becoming a sort of standard in cases where ++i vs i++ have the same functionally.

Answer (score -1):

Choosing `++i` instead there [would merely be a style choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61456492/4386278).

[There are no performance gains to be had in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887/4386278). That is a myth.

`i++` is also more "conventional" for a simple loop over `int`s.

You are of course free to write your own loop in your own style!

Comment: There may be performance issues depending on the data type and if the data type has overloaded the increment operators.  For integers, there is a performance difference, but compilers usually optimize it out.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews could you give examples of the performance difference for overloads and for unoptimized integer code?